# How use for loop in iterator

Tags: dart

I want to ask about `iterator` with a `list`, I can loop with a `list` in a `while loop`.

```
void main() {
  final myList = ['Red', 'Black', 'Green'];
  final myIterator = myList.iterator;

  while (myIterator.moveNext()) {
    print(myIterator.current);
  }
}
```

It is ok and works fine for me, but I want to know how I use `for loop`  or `for in loop` with `iterator`?

Comment: Why do you want to use a for loop whith the iterator ? I think it would just add difficulties to something quite simple whit a while loop.

Comment: If you want to use a `for` loop, you probably should use a `for`-`in` loop and not bother with manually using iterators at all.

Answer (score 1):

You rarely need to use an `Iterator` directly. It is a low level concept.

Use a for-in loop, like so:

```
for (final element in myList) {
  print(element);
}
```